# Why does my method display the full hash even when I have specified what to `puts` exactly?

Tags: ruby, terminal

I am trying to find the key and value of the second hash inside the first hash. That prints fine but at the end in the terminal it keeps printing out the full hash as well which is not what I want.
This is what the terminal prints

```
Egg Fried Rice
3.0
Fish and Chips
6.0
Cheese Pizza
8.0
Spicy Wings
4.0
Lamb Curry
5.0
 => {1=>{"Egg Fried Rice"=>3.0}, 2=>{"Fish and Chips"=>6.0}, 3=>{"Cheese Pizza"=>8.0}, 4=>{"Spicy Wings"=>4.0}, 5=>{"Lamb Curry"=>5.0}}
```

My code looks OK so I am not sure what I am missing or require.

```
class Menu
  attr_reader :menu_items

  def initialize
    @menu_items =
      {
        1 => { 'Egg Fried Rice' => 3.00 },
        2 => { 'Fish and Chips' => 6.00 },
        3 => { 'Cheese Pizza' => 8.00 },
        4 => { 'Spicy Wings' => 4.00 },
        5 => { 'Lamb Curry' => 5.00 }
      }
  end

  def display
    @menu_items.each do |_key, value|
      value.map do |item, price|
        puts item
        puts price
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why you use `map`? You'de better use `each` in this case.

Comment: ah sorry I pasted my previous code in. It does in fact both have each

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour if you run the code directly in `irb`.

Ruby return the last expression in a method by default.

Ruby's `irb` is a REPL meaning: `Read Evaluate Print Loop` so when you execute your method `display` in `irb` the REPL print last evaluated expression that happens to be the return value of the method `display`.

The method `display` returns the `Hash` because `Enumerable#each` returns self, that is the `Hash` object on which you called `each`.

You have three option to avoid `irb` printing the String representation of the `Hash`:

- Run the script as a `Shell` script
- Make the method `display` to  return an empty string
- Run the code as a ruby script.